# Newlines are missing in a few editing help sections

Tags: bug, editing-help

Consult our friendly [editing help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page. The following sections are missing newlines and appearing incorrectly:

- [Linebreaks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#linebreaks)
- [Simple blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes)
- [Advanced blockquotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#advanced-blockquotes)
- [Spoilers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers)

Here's what advanced blockquotes looks like, for example:

> [image: lots and lots of things on the same line that shouldn't be]